# Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out in /opt/lampp/htdocs/

Tags: php, mysql, angular, xampp, google-cloud-platform

I use ubuntu 18 server by google cloud instance
I installed xammp, status is:

> sudo /opt/lampp/lampp status
>
> Version: XAMPP for Linux 5.6.15-1
>
> Apache is running.
>
> MySQL is running.
>
> ProFTPD is running.

I send request http post by my angular application from localhost to this server.

It's not working.

this server application is PHP and mySql

when i browser the url server, i get error:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out in
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/dashboard/models/sql.php on line 12 Connection
> failed: Connection timed out

sql.php (line 12):

// Create connection

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

when I run those from localhost by xammp. it's working.

Thank!

Comment: Nothing to do with Angular.

Comment: Show some code. Timeouts can have many causes -- too slow queries, connection initialization issues etc.

Comment: I added code in the massage body.